# Org capture template output to two files

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I am currently using two separate Org files to manage my work Todos. One is a file that I edit directly and keep notes on each todo task (Work.org). The other is a schedule file which is synced with Google Calendar using org-gcal (Schedule.org).

At the moment I use two separate capture templates to save each todo in the two files, but this means that I have to insert data about them twice every time. Is there anyway to have one org capture template save its output to two separate files?

Comment: Why do you have to save the same thing to two files? What exactly does that accomplish? You can always add both files to your agenda: is that not enough?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook`. From the docstring:

```
Hook that is run before the finalization starts.
The capture buffer is current and still narrowed.
```

Your hook function would have to parse out the data you just entered then format it for your second file and write it out. Not ideal, but all I can think of.